# MySQL join two table query

Tags: mysql

I have two table, product and productimages

product table;

```
|----------------Table:product-|
|ID | tr_productname           |
|---|--------------------------|
| 1 | Computer                 |
| 2 | Telephone                |
| 3 | Television               |
| 4 | Mouse                    |
|------------------------------|
```

productimages table;

```
|-----------Table:productimages-|
|ID | productid  |  imageurl    |
|---|------------|--------------|
| 1 |     1      | computer.jpg |
| 2 |     1      | computer2.jpg|
| 3 |     2      | telephone.jpg|
| 4 |     2      | x.jpg        |
| 5 |     2      | abc.jpg      |
| 6 |     3      | tv.jpg       |
|-------------------------------|
```

I want list products with image but if image does'nt seem to record.
I want list all product.

**MyQuery;**

```
SELECT product.id, productcode, tr_productname, brand, imageurl 
FROM product 
LEFT JOIN productimages 
ON product.id = productimages.productid 
GROUP BY productimages.productid 
ORDER BY product.id DESC
```

**Result;**

```
|-----------------------------------RESULT----|
|ID | tr_productname           |    imageurl  |
|---|--------------------------|--------------|
| 1 | Computer                 | computer.jpg |
| 2 | Telephone                | telephone.jpg|
| 3 | Television               | tv.jpg       |
|------------------------------|--------------|
```

But no product with "4" ID

Comment: I guess you are looking for all images for per product and if yes try `group_concat(imageurl) as imageurl`

Comment: I try join and in select but didn't work. It work but 4th record not seem. Need productimages record for seem a product. I want get list all product. Didn't work group_concat(imageurl) as imageurl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change GROUP BY `productimages.productid` to `product.id` like this

```
SELECT product.id, productcode, tr_productname, brand, imageurl 
FROM product 
LEFT JOIN productimages 
ON product.id = productimages.productid 
GROUP BY product.id 
ORDER BY product.id DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this ..

```
SELECT product.id, productcode, tr_productname, brand, imageurl 
FROM product 
LEFT JOIN productimages 
ON product.id = productimages.productid 
GROUP BY product.id 
ORDER BY product.id DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are using group by, the value involves in group by only shown. In your case you have grouped based on productimages table, in this table 4 value is not present. So use product.id in group by.

```
SELECT product.id, productcode, tr_productname, brand, imageurl 
FROM product 
LEFT JOIN productimages 
ON product.id = productimages.productid 
GROUP BY product.id 
ORDER BY product.id DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT product.id, productcode, tr_productname, brand, imageurl 
FROM product 
LEFT JOIN productimages 
ON product.id = productimages.productid 
GROUP BY product.id 
ORDER BY product.id DESC
```

Comment: A code-only or query-only answer is not usually a "quality" answer. Please provide some explanation as to _why_ you believe that this answers the question.